# Xamarin Android unit test automation

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.android, nunit

I am using NUnitLite for unit tests in Xamarin android project. I can run the unit tests in debug mode on device or emulator by starting the project in VS, which will install the application and I can run tests on device/emulator.

I need to automate this in build process. How to automate this NUnitLite Testcases?

I am following the approach below:

1. Create a class extending from Xamarin.Android.NUnitLite.TestSuiteInstrumentation, and add the test assembly in OnCreate method.
2. Install the app in device.
3. Run the test cases using below command from ABD:

   ```
   adb shell am instrument -w com.package,mypackage/app.tests.TestInstrumentation
   ```

Is this approach correct? Or can this be done any simpler way from NUnitLite itself?

Comment: You can add the `adb shell am instrument ....` command to the your `.csproj` and run it via `msbuild`. : https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1649768-how-do-i-automate-an-android-unit-test-project-

Comment: Thanks sushi, For building I am following the same approach.  I just wanted to make sure about using "Xamarin.Android.NUnitLite.TestSuiteInstrumentation" class.

Comment: You need *someway* to execute the tests on the device, so either manually using the interface provided in the `TestSuiteActivity` or via `adb` and executing them via `TestSuiteInstrumentation`... I do not know of any other way, there may be some open-source pre-written msbuild tasks to help automate that, but in the end they will exec `adb`....